# macOs bash profile

Tags: bash, macos

macOs 11.7.8

При запуске терминала (стандартного в mac) загружается стандартный профиль, то есть если я начну вызывать `code .` то он он напишет:

```
yl@iMac-yl ~ % code .
zsh: command not found: code
```

в настройках профиля `.bash_profile` все прописано, и алиасы и пути запуска VSCode, но при запуске этот файл не загружается, и приходится в ручную запускать команду `source ~/.bash_profile` чтобы оживить терминал.

В папке `~` нашел еще два файла `.zprofile, .profile`, поменял в файле **.zprofile** настройки чтобы открывать не **.profile**, а **.bash_profile**, но и это не помогло, как решить эту головоломку?

Comment: вы же используете программу zsh в качестве командной оболочки. программа bash, следовательно, вашей ситуации никак не касается.

Answer (score 0):

Если у кого то такое будет то, заходим в настройки терминала, во вкладке основное пункт "Открытие Shell", прописываем путь `/bin/zsh` и все работает